# Swift IOS Spritekit Scaling Sprite Size Based on Device Size

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, size, scaling

For the past couple of weeks I have been dabbling with SpriteKit, Xcode, and Swift and despite doing a lot of research I have yet to find out the best way to manage sprite size between devices.

In my game I have found a somewhat round-about way of handling sprite size and position to make my sprites somewhat consistent between devices by manually adjusting characteristics like size, font size, and position with if statements checking for the height of the device. Ideally I would like my entire game views, including the sprites that they house, to be sized proportionally to the device size. I have tried messing with the different SKSceneScaleModes but nothing is really doing the trick.

My question: What is the most efficient way of handling sprite size and positioning between devices in SpriteKit (more specifically in Swift)? I don't care too much about supporting the iPad, mainly just the iPhone 4s - 6 plus. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Imo, simply scaling relative to the GameScene's size is good enough. In `GameViewController`, I initialize the scene to be the `view.bounds.size`. When you create your sprite, just make a `setScale` call to make it proportional to `view.bounds.size`. Since `view.bounds.size` is based on how big the screen is, you'll get proportionally bigger images for bigger screened devices.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, but how will I make a sprite proportional to `view.bounds.size`, since it, in a iPhone 5s, for example, returns (568.0, 320.0)?

Comment: Been a year since I touched `SpriteKit`, but I believe there is a `setScale` method for all SK objects. Just call that and pass in `view.bounds.size / someValue`, where someValue is how you want to scale it based on the view size.